Is there a way in google charts to make two tooltips
I have a requirement in which I want to add two tooltips in google-react-charts. One tooltip shows data of all y axis series, which I am able to do by using focusTarget: 'category'. Other tooltip shows data of x-axis on hovering. Look of both the tooltips is different. I know google-reacts-charts does not support multiple tooltips. But can anyone suggest some workaround for this?
I tried cursor, annotations, pointshape. But nothing is giving me expected result.

will you please clarify the following? do you want to display two tooltips at the same time? or different tooltips depending on which chart element is hovered?
